# it show Uncaught ReferenceError: initializeApp is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show 'blogs' from my database in my web page. I already include the packages `firebase-app` and `firebase-database`,
but still it does not recognize `initializeApp`.

It show:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: initializeApp is not defined

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2> hello world </h2>

    <!-- the functions you need from the SDKs you need-->

        <!-- Import the functions you need from the SsDKs you need-->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-database.js"></script>


    <script>
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDwq-CA3Fm1oYj3jLnPeeczNb9xXrKYtbo",
    authDomain: "firebasic-a87d7.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://firebasic-a87d7-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app",
    projectId: "firebasic-a87d7",
    storageBucket: "firebasic-a87d7.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "701224819501",
    appId: "1:701224819501:web:69eedfd3468db6f3f511a4",
    measurementId: "G-WVEYYLK2VJ"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = firebase.database();
  const blogRef = db.ref(blogs).on('value',handleSuccess,handleError);

  function handleSuccess(items){
      console.log(items);
}

  function handleError(error){
      console.log(error);
}

 
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`initializeApp` / `firebase.initializeApp` are available when `firebase-app.js` had been loaded.

Rather use [v9](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/alt-setup#from-the-cdn), which still can be setup through CDN:

```
<body>

  <!-- Insert this script at the bottom of the HTML, but before you use any Firebase services -->
  <script type="module">
    import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.2/firebase-app.js'
    import { auth } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.2/firebase-auth.js'
    import { database } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.2/firebase-database.js'
  </script>
</body>
```

---

Or [v8](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#web-version-8) with deferred loading:

```
<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-database.js"></script>   
<script defer src="./init-firebase.js"></script>
```

File `init-firebase.js`:

```
var firebaseConfig = { ... };
firebase.initializeApp( firebaseConfig );
```

Comment: it show 

Uncaught ReferenceError: initializeApp is not defined
    at index.html:37
(anonymous) @ index.html:37
index.html:16 Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.2/firebase-database.js' does not provide an export named 'database'

Answer (score 0):

Firebase will add a global object in your window, `firebase` that hold the initializeApp method, so you have to access it through the `firebase` object but you cannot call `initializeApp` directly

BTW, your config has an invalid `firebase/database URL

please consider watching this video to have an intro about FB DB
[Get started with Firebase on web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1D0_wFlXgo)

Make sure to change your app and DB credentials on Firebase, cause they're public now everyone saw them

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2> hello world </h2>

    <!-- the functions you need from the SDKs you need-->

    <!-- Import the functions you need from the SsDKs you need-->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.7.0/firebase-database.js"></script>


    <script defer async>
        console.log(firebase);
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyDwq-CA3Fm1oYj3jLnPeeczNb9xXrKYtbo",
            authDomain: "firebasic-a87d7.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://firebasic-a87d7-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app",
            projectId: "firebasic-a87d7",
            storageBucket: "firebasic-a87d7.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "701224819501",
            appId: "1:701224819501:web:69eedfd3468db6f3f511a4",
            measurementId: "G-WVEYYLK2VJ"
        };

        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const db = firebase.database();
        const blogRef = db.ref(blogs).on('value', handleSuccess, handleError);

        function handleSuccess(items) {
            console.log(items);
        }

        function handleError(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```